# How can I use d3pie.js to scroll and appear?

Tags: jquery, charts

I want to use this [example](http://d3pie.org/website/examples/donut.html) on my website.

But there is a question, I want it to appear when I scroll to the pie, How can I do this?

Like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8YVUb/64/)

I used jquery.appear.js but don't know how to do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/morr/jquery.appear/master/jquery.appear.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        $('#pie').appear(function() {

        });
    });
    </script>
```

Please help, Thanks!